# How to convert to json file

Tags: json, bash

I am writing a bash script utilizing to json

Example

This is my input file:

```
{
  "action_name": "pushed to",
  "created_at": "2021-11-04T07:49:43.553Z",
  "author": {
    "name": "Foo Name",
    "username": "foo"
  },
  "push_data": {
    "action": "pushed",
    "ref": "master",
    "commit_title": "#152069 Update foo"
  },
  "author_username": "foo"
}
{
  "action_name": "pushed to",
  "created_at": "2021-11-04T07:48:12.211Z",
  "author": {
    "name": "Bar Name",
    "username": "bar"
  },
  "push_data": {
    "action": "pushed",
    "ref": "feature/dev",
    "commit_title": "#152069 Update bar"
  },
  "author_username": "bar"
}
```

I want to convert these into json like below

```
[
    {"created_at": "2021-11-04T07:49:43.553Z", "action_name": "pushed to", "name": "Foo Name", "ref": "master", "commit_title": "#152069 Update foo"},
    {"created_at": "2021-11-04T07:48:12.211Z", "action_name": "pushed to", "name": "Bar Name", "ref": "feature/dev", "commit_title": "#152069 Update bar"}
]
```

Please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: What do you want the CSV output to contain? Your expected results is more JSON.

Comment: And your input file has multiple independent objects?

Comment: @Shawn yes, input file has multiple independent objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, `jq`, the de factor standard tool for working with JSON data in shell scripts, understands input files with multiple JSON values, instead of requiring only one value per file like some programs. Creating an array of objects using data from the input objects is trivial:

```sh
$ jq -n '[ inputs | { created_at, action_name, name: .author.name, ref: .push_data.ref,
                      commit_title: .push_data.commit_title } ]' input.json
[
  {
    "created_at": "2021-11-04T07:49:43.553Z",
    "action_name": "pushed to",
    "name": "Foo Name",
    "ref": "master",
    "commit_title": "#152069 Update foo"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2021-11-04T07:48:12.211Z",
    "action_name": "pushed to",
    "name": "Bar Name",
    "ref": "feature/dev",
    "commit_title": "#152069 Update bar"
  }
]
```